# Typescript Class Singleton vs Module Singleton

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

I was looking at some code in the vscode repository and noticed they used a class singleton for one of the modules see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/base/browser/browser.ts).

Would it not be much cleaner to write this just as a regular module? What are the benefits of wrapping this up in a class, creating a singleton instance, and exporting the methods?

Comment: maybe to keep global scope clean.

Comment: what? that is not how module imports work... variables are scoped to the module.

Comment: Then there is only one difference which is private properties of the class. Considering they would already be private members in a module, yet they made them private members of a class seems like nothing related to usage of a module, but to the functions inside module. They limited inner functions' access to specific data.

Comment: It's just bad practice. Maybe they have contributors from OOP languages.

Comment: @Paleo that was my assumption, thanks.